# extracts value from xml nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml

> I am trying to extracts some values and colonnes from xml nodes but it
>   is working . this is my code

```
Drop table #TableXML 
CREATE TABLE #TableXML(Col1 int primary key, Col2 xml) 
Insert into #TableXML values ( 1,
'<CookedUP>
  <Evenement Calcul="16">
    <Cookie xmlns="http://services.ariel.morneausobeco.com/2007/02" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <AlternateOptionTypeCodes />
      <Cash>0</Cash>
      <CashInterest>0</CashInterest>
      <CashSource>Undefined</CashSource>
      <Code>A</Code>
      <SmallAmount>0</SmallAmount>
      <SmallAmountType>Undefined</SmallAmountType>
    </Cookie>
  </Evenement>
</CookedUP> '
)




SELECT  b.Col1,
        x.XmlCol.value('(Cookie/SmallAmount)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS SmallAmount,
        x.XmlCol.value('(Cookie/cash)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS cash
FROM    #TableXML b
CROSS APPLY b.Col2.nodes('/CookedUP/Evenement') x(XmlCol)
```

when i ran this query , i am getting null values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your node `Cookie` has a namespace, so you need to declare that and and use it as part of your path (as it isn't the default namespace). Also, you had `cash` instead of `Cash` (xQuery is case sensitive). Thus you get:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://services.ariel.morneausobeco.com/2007/02' AS ns)
SELECT b.Col1,
       x.XmlCol.value('(ns:Cookie/ns:SmallAmount/text())[1]', 'int') AS SmallAmount,
       x.XmlCol.value('(ns:Cookie/ns:Cash/text())[1]', 'int') AS Cash
FROM #TableXML b
     CROSS APPLY b.Col2.nodes('CookedUP/Evenement') x(XmlCol);
```

I also changed the datatype to `int` (this may not be the correct datatype, you might want `decimal`), as the data is clearly numerical and added `/text()` to the values (I can't remember the exact reason, but the use of `/text()` has a performance benefit).

Comment: wow simply the best answer , thanks so much @larnu this works perfectly as i wished